# Display Google Keywords that brought a user to the site

Tags: php, javascript, search, seo

I am looking to display something like:

Hello, you've reached this site by looking for [google keyword(s)]

I'm pretty sure I've seen this done before but I am having troubles figuring out how to grab the keywords that were used to lead a user to my site. Anyone know the answer?

Comment: I can't give you the answer, but the following: I really hate when a website welcomes me with my google search term. Sorry, but I know the terms I entered just a few seconds ago. Other than that, good luck finding a valid technical answer.

Comment: i don't think he wants it for displaying the annoying message. probably wants to store/analyse it.

Comment: I'll have to agree with OregonGhost, website that do that annoys me.

Comment: I hear you guys, I'm not a fan of it either. Client gets what client wants though right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the referring URL and then strip out everything for the "q" query string.  This will give you the query that was used to get you to your page.

Comment: its not working anymore, google has stopped sending complete information in HTTP_REFERRER

Answer (score 1):

Using the referrer (http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/javascript_no14.htm) you can find where the user comes from. Then it's just a matter of parsing it correctly.

---

I saw this script :

```
function getkeywords() {
    var x = document.referrer;
    var lastparturl = 0;
    if (x.search(/google/) != -1) {
        lastparturl = x.indexOf("&btnG=Google+Search"); 
        x = x.slice(38,lastparturl); 
        x = x.concat("via google");
    }
    else if (x.search(/yahoo/) != -1) {
        lastparturl = x.indexOf("&ei=UTF-8&iscqry=&fr=sfp"); 
        x = x.slice(63,lastparturl); 
        x = x.concat("via yahoo");
    }
    else if (x.search(/ask.com/) != -1) {
        lastparturl = x.indexOf("&search=search&qsrc=0&o=0&l=dir"); 
        x = x.slice(25,lastparturl); 
        x = x.concat("via ask");
    }
    else if (x.search(/dogpile/) != -1) {
        lastparturl = x.indexOf("/1/417/TopNavigation/Relevance/iq=true/zoom=off/_iceUrlFlag=7?_IceUrl=true"); 
        x = x.slice(46,lastparturl); 
        x = x.concat("via dogpile");
    }
    else if (x.search(/altavista/) != -1) {
        lastparturl = x.indexOf("&kgs=1&kls=0"); 
        x = x.slice(48,lastparturl); 
        x = x.concat("via altavista");
    }
    else { 
        x = "no keywords available";
    } 
    x = x.replace(/+/, " ");
    return x; 
}
```

Here http://www.webmonkey.com/codelibrary/Get_Referrer_Keywords

I'm not sure if it works perfectly, but it worked OK when I reached their website through google.

I also saw that some scripts that you can download do that, for instance: http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Search-Engines/Keyword-Grabber-45299.html

Again, this will need to be tested.